# Four similar words; synonyms

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

1. The first three letters are similar for the first and second words (eg, **'' 'pre' ach'' &  " 'pre' tty"**). And three of them ends with letter 'e' especially one which ends with letter 'h'.
2. Also, the first three letters are similar for the third and last words
3. When you remove two letters from one of them, it'll mean, "noise of heavy things breaking"
4. If you remove two letters from the other one, it'll mean, "step"

All of these words are synonyms.

Answer (score 4):

Possible solution with appropriate corrections to the question:

> **collapsed, crashed, collided, treaded**

I took the liberty to make some grammatical and typographical corrections as follows.

1. The first three letters of two words are the same

> **coll**apsed and **coll**ided

2. The *last* three letters of two words are the same (assuming first $\to$ last)

> colli**ded** and trea**ded**

3. When you remove two letters from one of them, it'll mean, "noise of heavy things breaking"

> [**crash**](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=-pJt0VIrOU0C&pg=PA131&lpg=PA131&dq=%22noise+of+heavy+things+breaking%22&source=bl&ots=n1se-2NFEO&sig=ACfU3U1UAnicwB1VPPY4vh_NG9VGPN-pGA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi89omqn_PnAhV_zjgGHbQ1CVYQ6AEwAHoECAUQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22noise%20of%20heavy%20things%20breaking%22&f=false)ed

4. If you remove two letters from the other one, it'll mean, "step"

> **tread**ed

All of these words are synonyms.

> **collapsed, crashed, collided,** and **treaded** share a common meaning.

Comment: Hi, there's no error(s), the first three letters of the first word resembles the first three letters of the second word. Also, the first three letters of the third word resembles the first three letters of the fourth word.

Answer (score 3):

After the clarification, the solution could be

> **cracked, crashed, tramped, trampled**

1. The first three letters of the first and second words are the same

> **cra**cked and **cra**shed

2. The first three letters of the third and fourth words are the same

> **tra**mped and **tra**mpled

3. When you remove two letters from one of them, it'll mean, "noise of heavy things breaking"

> [**crash**](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=-pJt0VIrOU0C&pg=PA131&lpg=PA131&dq=%22noise+of+heavy+things+breaking%22&source=bl&ots=n1se-2NFEO&sig=ACfU3U1UAnicwB1VPPY4vh_NG9VGPN-pGA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi89omqn_PnAhV_zjgGHbQ1CVYQ6AEwAHoECAUQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22noise%20of%20heavy%20things%20breaking%22&f=false)ed

4. If you remove two letters from the other one, it'll mean, "step"

> [**tramp**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/step)ed

All of these words are synonyms.

> **cracked, crashed, tramped,** and **trampled** share a common meaning